# Powershell, Excel path in cell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have a workbook with a path in a cell I looked up before.
The value in that cell is: "C:\Test\1". Now I want to get that path in a variable.

Let's say I'm already on the actual cell.

This is what I tried:

```
$RGPath = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(1).Select
```

Now if I do:

```
Write-Host $RGPath
```

This is what I get: "System.__ComObject" and that's not the path.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be `$RGPath = $Worksheet.Cells.Item(1)` (no select) and to access the cell's value use `$RGPath.value`

Comment: Hi Daniel, still the same thing. Shouldn't "Write-Host $RGPath" return the value from cell A1?

Comment: It appears so, though I personally would do `Write-Host $($RGPath.Value)`.  You still need to remove .Select.  .Select is an action that selects the cell but does not return the range.  `$Worksheet.Cells.Item(1)` will return the range.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it done:

```
$excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
$Excel.visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($file)

$Worksheets = $Workbooks.worksheets
$Worksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("KD_RG")
$Range = $Worksheet.Range("B1").EntireColumn
$Search = $Range.find($RGFileName)
$Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 2)
$RGPath = $Worksheet.Cells($Search.Row, $Search.Column + 2)
$RGPath = $RGPath.Value()
```